# Is it possible to implement multiple foldernames in an rm -rf query in osc Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, directory, rm

I am trying to delete certain subfolders in a directory.

When using the following promt:

`cd` to root of directory Y

then (assuming the folder name is "X",):

`find . -name X -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Is it possible to implement multiple target folders besides X?

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name X1 -or -name X2 -type d -depth 1 ...
```

`-type d` will only find directories.

`-depth 1` limits it to subdirectories of the current directory (i.e. the directories listed by `ls` with no arguments).